# Placing files in folders using PuTTY

Tags: windows-10, putty

I'm new to things like putty and am trying to upload a file from my own computer to a to a folder on a server for a project I'm working on. so I know how to navigate to the folder I want to place files in when I use putty, I'm just a little confused on accessing files on my own computer. Also I'm using Windows 10.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about placing files in folders using putty. Putty is a terminal program that connects to a server over ssh. There are tools to upload files over ssh, but those tools are not putty.

Some tools:
**mobaxterm** : includes tabbed ssh terminals, you can up- and download files, has a free version

**winscp**: free tool to upload and download files using ssh

For windows 10 users: you can enable the **windows bash** shell. This shell has commands like 'ssh' for terminal access and 'scp' for copying files over ssh

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY doesn't actually have a "file upload" feature on its own. It does come with two SFTP (SSH file transfer) clients, `psftp` for interactive CLI and `pscp` for batch mode:

```
C:\Projects\Foo> psftp user@server.example.tld
psftp> cd /var/www/foo
psftp> put index.html
```

Graphical SFTP clients include WinSCP, FileZilla, Bitvise Tunnelier.

---

(For something really old-school, you could use KiTTY as the client, install `rz` on the server, and transfer files via Zmodem.)